# Git Rebase merge auto take

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have

```
              G---H---I---J    Develop
             /
A---B---C---D---E---F    Master
```

I want to rebase Develop with master, so:

```
                      G---H---I---J    Develop
                     /
A---B---C---D---E---F    Master
```

So if I do `git checkout develop & git rebase master`

It will do the rebase, however, at each commit where it finds a merge conflict it will stop.

I'm happy just to take everything from develop and overwrite with that. There have been massive changes with develop but each commit builds and passes all tests, so I can assume if I just overwrite everything in master it should be fine.

So how do I say something like `git rebase master --choose develop side`

Comment: Would it be possible to stash G-J develop, then merge master to develop (perhaps this is a fast-forward) but then after develop is in sync with master, git pop develop's stash changes as the next commit?  Is there a better way to do this without loosing changes to develop from master, and without conflicting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be `git rebase -X theirs master`

Comment: During a rebase "ours" and "theirs" become flipped.  So the correct command needs to be `git rebase -X ours master `  Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---merge

Comment: @MaxFriederichs: well, yes, but the OP said he wanted to choose the "develop" side, which is in fact `-X theirs`.

Comment: That will only resolve merge conflicts in favor of the branch, which isn't exactly how I'd read what was asked, and in any case is very likely to create non-functioning commits

Comment: @torek To choose the "develop" side, from the "develop" branch, during a rebase... You need to use "ours" (Yes, this is not intuitive)

Comment: @MaxFriederichs: one starts with `git checkout master` (either manually or via rebase), followed by a series of cherry-picks, in this case of commits `G`, then `H`, then `I`, then `J`, each from `develop`. The HEAD at the first cherry-pick is commit `F`; that's `--ours`. The merge base is `D` and `--theirs` corresponds to commit `G`. So if you want to resolve a conflict by choosing base-vs-`G`, you need `--theirs` here. The second through last cherry-picks are uglier as the merge base becomes `G`, then `H`, then `I`; at this point `--ours` refers to the commits you've been building.

Comment: Personally, I would not recommend using `-X` at all for these cases, for the reason @MarkAdelsberger notes.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some ambiguity in the statement

> I'm happy just to take everything from develop and overwrite with that

(or at least in how people are readying it).

Do you mean "where there's a conflict I'm happy taking what's in `develop`"?  That's what junkangli's answer (`git rebase -X theirs master`) is about.  And while that is one way to understand what you asked, it is unlikely that the result will be code that builds and runs.

Another way to read this would be that you want to take *everything* - conflicting or not - from `develop` - i.e. discard any changes that were made in `E` and `F` because the changes from `develop` were so profound that `E` and `F` just aren't worth the trouble any more.

In that case, you have a few options, depending on what you want in the final history.

My recommendation would be:

```
    # make sure you're on master
git checkout master
    # revert the commits that are going to be clobbered
git revert -n HEAD^ HEAD
git commit
    # merge the branch
git merge develop
```

This preserves `E` and `F` in history, along with a commit that clearly says "I'm consciously undoing these changes".  You'd end up with

```
              G - H -- I -- J    Develop
             /               \
A - B - C - D - E - F - ~EF - M    Master
```

Since you were wanting to rebase, you might not like that end state.  Another option is to do the revert as above, then rebase develop to master; since the content (`TREE`) at `~EF` matches the tree at `D`, this *should* work without conflict and give you

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - ~EF - G` - H` - I` - J`    Develop , Master
```

Assuming `develop` had previously been pushed, after doing this you would have to "force push" it (`push -f`); and this will create an "upstream rebase" situation for all other users of the repo; see the `git rebase` docs for more information including the steps for them to recover, and understand that if you don't coordinate with everyone affected, someone taking the *wrong* steps to recover could undo what you've done.

For completeness, the actual simplest approach (but not one I recommend, especially if others share the repo) would be to just `reset` the `master` ref to `J`.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard develop
```

This would rewrite the history of the `master` branch, so to push `master` you'd have to use the `-f` option (force push); and this again creates what is effectively an "upstream rebase" situation.  It also means that `E` and `F` are scrubbed from history altogether (unless you put a new tag or branch on them).

Comment: This is another interesting way to do it.